# How to detect which element in a class has a certain style

Tags: javascript, dom, if-statement, for-loop, styles

I have a series of `select` lists that share a class. They're all on top of each other, and one has `display: inline` while the others have `display: none`. How could I use plain JavaScript (no jQuery) to find the list that is showing and retrieve its `value`?

I was thinking something like this:

```
function retrieve() {
  var value
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('class');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].style.display = 'inline') {
      value = elements[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }
  alert(value);
}
```

But the alert says "undefined". What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
if(elements[i].style.display = 'inline') {
```

should be

```
if(elements[i].style.display === 'inline') {
// change here --------------^
```

With the single `=`, it's an *assignment*, not a comparison. With the `===`, it's a ([strict](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6)) comparison. You could also use `==` (a [loose comparison](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)).

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference between a strict/loose comparison?

Comment: @Ian: In a loose comparison, `"0" == 0` is `true`. In a strict comparison, `"0" === 0` is `false`. E.g., a loose comparison will do type conversion, a strict one won't. Makes no difference if (as in this case) you know the types of the operands, but can make a big difference if you're not sure of their types (in which case, usually best to intentionally convert them to something you know and use `===`; the implicit type conversion rules are quite complex). Added links.